# option '--opt' cannot be specified more than once

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Running into an error from boost program options. I am running a command such as `prog --opt arg1 --opt arg2`.

It returns this error

> option '--opt' cannot be specified more than once.

Is there a way to use the option name more than once?

Currently I have the program option defined as such and it has no default value. I am interested in figuring out a way to specify the use of the option name several times

```
po::value<std::string>()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-boost-program_options:

**Specify an option that can be specified multiple times**

--option <value1> --option <value2> --option <value3>

`("option", po::value<std::vector<arg_type> >(), "a list of values")`

Comment: Can you please fix the link?